# JPA with EJB: No persistence provider

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to run my first app using JPA but it seems the problem is that persistence.xml is not found.

```
run:
 [java] Driver loaded successfull.
 [java] Got connection.
 [java] Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named books
 [java]     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:84)
 [java]     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
 [java]     at com.primaryAnalysis.Main.main(Unknown Source)
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

The project structure is the same:

```
src
├── java
│   └── com
│       ├── ejb
│       │   └── Persistence
│       │       └── ejb3-persistence.jar
│       ├── mysql
│       │   └── jdbc
│       │       └── Driver
│       │           └── mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar
│       └── primaryAnalysis
│           ├── ...
└── resources
    └── META-INF
        └── persistence.xml
```

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="books" transaction-type="JTA">
            <provider>com.ejb.Persistence</provider>
            <class>com.primaryAnalysis.Book</class>
            <class>com.primaryAnalysis.Autor</class>
            <properties>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"   value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/books" />
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"     value="root" />
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="MyNewPass" />
                    <property name="toplink.ddl-generation"          value="create-tables" />
            </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

I have the path to *resource* directory in *taskdef resource* in my build.xml.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe `META-INF` should be under `src/resources`. It should be at your project's root directory.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  In a Maven project, there's absolutely nothing wrong with it living under /resources.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I've tried to put META-INF in my project's root directory but it still didn't work.

Comment: @mortalland Can you tell me what the jar you generate looks like internally?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: It has META-INF directory inside with a manifest file and com directory. It seems it should have persistence.xml in META-INF. Am I right?

Comment: @mortalland According to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/build/reference/en/html/entityconfig.html), you are right. So your build.xml (ant?) or maven is not building your project the way you want it to. It doesn't actually matter where the `persistence.xml` file is when developing, as long as your build script actually puts it in the jar `META-INF` directory.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/build/reference/en/html/entityconfig.html), the `persistence.xml` file should be found in your project jar's `META-INF` folder. It doesn't matter where it is when you are developing in your IDE project structure, but your build tool should place it under `META-INF` in your jar.

With ant (build.xml)

```
<copy todir="some_folder/temp">
    <fileset dir="src/resources" /> // copies everything under src/resources to some_folder/temp
</copy>

<jar jarfile="some_folder/bin/your_app.jar">
    <fileset dir="some_folder/temp" /> // put the folder from before in your jar
</jar>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<provider>com.ejb.Persistence</provider>
```

Wat?

Google search test ( [Google: "com.ejb.Persistence"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&safe=off&q=%22com.ejb.Persistence%22)  ) says that this is something very special (rare):

```
16 results
```

and results are:

```
1. <provider>com.ejb.Persistence</provider> - this question
2. <local>com.ejb.persistence.UserLocal</local> - some samples from india's guest at oracle forum
3. no exact match
4 - 9. search spam sites webwiki.com codeweblog.com ineedfile2.com webstatsdomain.com
10 - 16. "java-enterprise-app.developerfaqs.com.ejb.finder" at ejb.developerfaqs.com/
```

So I'm almost sure that you have no valid provider named "com.ejb.Persistence" in folder "src/java/com/ejb/persistence/" (note, this is incorrect folder for com.ejb.Persistence class, it should be sewed as "com/ejb/Persistence.class" ) or in the jar file `ejb3-persistence.jar`. I have a copy of this file from [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/ejb3-persistence/3.3.2.Beta1) and according to structure of this jar it has only javax.persistence.* classes and no any com.ejb.* classes.

I think you can switch to eclipselink jpa provider (download "Installer Zip (37 MB)" from http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/ and extract combined jar from "eclipselink/jlib/eclipselink.jar"):

```
  <persistence-unit name="books" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
     <class>com.primaryAnalysis.Book</class>
     <class>com.primaryAnalysis.Autor</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/books"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="MyNewPass"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```